# Microsoft Edge does not render masked svg

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to mask a svg icon to change its color. Each icon's can have different colors, so I want to just load it once and change the color on the client side. This works well in all browsers except in Microsoft Edge. I created a html example to reproduce the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg version="1.2" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <defs>
                <mask id="icon">
                    <image xlink:href="./icon.svg" width="100%" height="100%" />
                </mask >
            </defs>
            <rect fill="red" mask="url(#icon)" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The svg looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="nonzero" clip-rule="evenodd" viewBox="0 0 10240 10240" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>office_building icon</title>
    <path id="curve2" fill="#ffffff" d="M6080,8000 7360,8000 7360,9600 6080,9600z"/>
    <path id="curve1" fill="#ffffff" d="M4160 5120l5120 0c176,0 320,144 320,320l0 4160 -1920 0 0 -1920 -1920 0 0 1920 -1920 0 0 -4160c0,-176 144,-320 320,-320zm320 2560l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm2 -1928l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-2 1928l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0z"/>
    <path id="curve0" fill="#ffffff" d="M960 640l5120 0c176,0 320,144 320,320l0 3840 -2240 0c-353,0 -640,287 -640,640l0 4160 -2880 0 0 -8640c0,-176 144,-320 320,-320zm320 4480l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm3840 -1920l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm3840 -1920l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm1280 5760l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm-1280 0l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0zm1280 -1920l0 1280 640 0 0 -1280 -640 0z"/>
</svg>
```

If this example is opened in Edge, nothing is showing. In all other browsers the icon is correctly shown in red.

In my project the svg's are loaded via service, but this is not the problem as you can see in my example. Also it must be loaded via service, because the icons can change at a later time.
Switching to png, which would then work, is currently not an option.

Is there a way to make this work in Edge with svg's or is it just not possible currently?

Answer (score -1):

Edge does not support svg masks by MDN [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility) at the moment.

**Update Jan 2024**

Svg masks are supported as of 2020[image]